# Simple ScaleAnimation on TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-animation

I would like to know how to make a very quick and simple `ScaleAnimation` in Android on a `TextView` that does this:

User clicks on a submit `button`  and a `TextView` Gets two times the size and returns back to normal.  I would like to see this smooth transition in Text Size.  So I'd like to watch it grow and then shrink.

Not sure if I can do this without an `XML` file or if it is better with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is similar to the [following tutorial](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.ca/2008/04/animated-views.html), which shows how to run an animation that increases the size of a textView when selected. The code shown below is taken from said tutorial.

The animation file can be defined in xml as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXScale="0.5"
android:toXScale="2.0"
android:fromYScale="0.5"
android:toYScale="2.0"
android:pivotX="0%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:startOffset="0"
android:duration="400"
android:fillBefore="true" />
```

> Not sure if I can do this without an XML file or if it is better with?

The only reason to do it in Java is because you have to compute the values for scaling the view. Other than that, go with xml.